# Kendo .template and .custom together

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, toolbar

```
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
      toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Task");=
      toolbar.Custom().Name("PullItemsFromSubTeams").Url("").Text("Pull Items From Individual Assessments");
      toolbar.Custom().Name("GroupItems").Url("").Text("Group Items");
      toolbar.Custom().Name("Group").Url("").Text("Group Items");
      toolbar.Custom().Name("cancel").Url("").Text("Cancel");
      toolbar.Excel();
      toolbar.Pdf();
      toolbar.Template("<input type='checkbox' name = 'items[]' class = 'items' value='#= Id #'/>");
  })
```

I need to use custom buttons and template, because I need to add input to Kendo toolbar, my code is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to combine a Grid toolbar template with standalone custom command declarations. Either include all commands (buttons) inside the template, or use commands only.

Comment: No, I am afraid not.